# Opening different application from an Android activity and getting and storing screenshots

Tags: android

I am creating an automation application wherein I have to store screenshots of other applications home page in real time.

I have the following problem statement..

Suppose I have an app A and app B. I want that my app A should periodically open app B everyday at a specified time and catch the screenshot and close that app and in the mean while fetch the screenshots in the application A(or to some server and access given to app A)and create a record day wise.

Can you help me with the process as to automate things without using a button?

Key Challenges

1. Navigate from activity on app A to open app B without button click(like a scheduler).
2. Taking screenshots in the meanwhile and fetching it from gallery and uploading it to the server.
3. Closing this app and giving the control back to app A as soon as pics are uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem statement reflects the spy intentions, I assume the solutions I provide are not used to infringe any privacy or personal data of potential users.

We will go one by one according to requirements.

1. **Launching another app from your app**: You should know the package name of app you wish to open. If you wish to make this dynamic. Here's the code to list out all the apps installed on the device.

   ```
   final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   //get a list of installed apps.
   List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
       Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
       Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
   }
   ```

   Package name you retrieve here can be used to launch the main activity of respective application. Here's the code for the same:

   ```
   Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Enter package name here");
   if (launchIntent != null) { 
       startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
   }
   ```
2. **Automating task at periodic intervals**: Put this code in your activity where the user set the alarm.

   ```
   public void setAlarm(){

       BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent _ )
           {
               //launch application and screenshot code here
               context.unregisterReceiver( this ); // this == BroadcastReceiver, not Activity
           }
       };

       this.registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("any_custom_message") );

       PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("custom_message_used_above"), 0 );
       AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

       // set alarm to fire 5 sec (1000*5) from now (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
       manager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10*60*60 //10 minutes in millis, pintent );
   }
   ```

   Update Manifest for permissions:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
   ```
3. **Take screenshot of the app opened**: This is not possible through API as it can cause privacy issues. We will try this out using chathead similar services. They run as a service and uses Window to draw widgets and layout. Hence Window layout can be used to capture Screenshot. Go to this [blog post](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) and learn how to create chatheads. In this case there should not be any design for chathead as its main purpose is to capture screenshot. Now to take screenshot use the following code:

   ```
   Bitmap bitmap;
   View v1 = //Your root layout after inflating to WindowManager
   v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
   v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
   ```
4. **Storing and sending to server**:

   ```
   String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" +  YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME;
   OutputStream fout = null;
   imageFile = new File(mPath);

   try {
       fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
       fout.flush();
       fout.close();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   You can use any library like Volley or retrofit to send this file to server. Here's a link of [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/).

**I hope this solves most of the problems of your statement. I might have skipped some common stuff such as permission of file read and write. Please do include those as I haven't run the code and tried.**

Comment: As far as privacy is concerned we cannot upload the screenshots to server without user selecting it??? Is it anyhow possible to automate the process of uploading the screenshots that have been taken with this app??

Comment: Files can be uploaded using a background service. USer selecting it is not mandatory. Though you should always make user aware of activity going on in background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach

1. Create a sticky service.
2. Create a combination on PendingIntent+AlarmManager that will run the above service at a perticular time everyday.
3. The service will open the appB and take a screenshot.
4. Once done, the service will close appB.
5. Then it will fetch the image and upload it on the server.
6. After the upload is successful, the service will stop and update the AlarmManager.

The same will repeat everyday.

Not sure this will work or not, but you can try

hope this helps. :)